# Bundle install issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle

I add some gem to my gemfile.

Then i type :

`$ bundle install`

It will install the newly add gems in general , But it install the all gems, and it very slowly.

This is my terminal output:

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system:
Using rake (10.1.0)
Using i18n (0.6.5)
...
```

So:

How to make the `bundle install` fast, and i don't want it always install all gems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see `Using gemname (version)`, it means the gem is already installed and Bundler doesn't reinstall it.

Comment: Ok, i got, But it still slowly. I just installed a gem,but it takes me a few minutes

Comment: @user3060257 maybe your internet connection isn't the speed demon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bundle install all of your gems as there are dependency requirements between them. Bundler doesn't reinstall the gem's which state `Using rake (10.1.0)`, but just confirms it's version to ensure gem dependency and prevent your application from producing runtime errors.

You can find out more information here: 
http://bundler.io/